# Annihilator of a module homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, quotient-spaces, module-isomorphism

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $M$ and $N$ be $R$-modules. Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be an ideal in the annihilator of $M$ and in the annihilator of $N$. An $R$-homomorphism $f: M\to N$ is in particular a $R/\mathfrak{a}$-homomorphism. However, is there an isomorphism of $R/\mathfrak{a}$-modules or $R$-modules
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{R}(M, N)\cong\mathrm{Hom}_{R/\mathfrak{a}}(M, N)?$$

I believe there is an isomorphism of $R$-modules and of $R/\mathfrak{a}$-modules, given by the identity $f\mapsto f$. Does anyone disagree with this evaluation?

Comment: Yes both, but do write out how the hom s are endowed with module structure for each.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is an isomorphism of $R/\mathfrak{a}$-modules.

Let's write out how the hom s are endowed with module structure for each to see that this preservation is a matter of how to view the $Hom_R(M,N)$ as an $R/\mathfrak{a}$ module.

The action of $R$ on a module $P$ can be written as $\mu : R × P → P$ or as a map $R  ⊗P  →P$. It seems to have caused some confusion that I used the latter approach, so let's keep things simple and switch to using $μ$ above.

The main question is, what is μ (the multiplication making something a module) for the case of ${End}_R(M,N)$ and $R/\mathfrak{a}$?

$Hom_R(M,N)$ has the module structure given by $f ⊗ r ↦ (a ↦ rf(a) = f(ra))$. That's the tensor approach but you can also think about the function

$$R × Hom_R(M,N) → Hom_R(M,N)$$

such that

$$(r, f) ↦ f_r $$
where $f_r$ sends $a$ to $rf(a)$.

Using the tensor approach, in which we describe the structure map of a module using the tensor product, $Hom_{R/\mathfrak{a}}(M,N)$ has the unique module structure sending a simple tensor $f ⊗ r$ to $(a ↦ \overline{r}f(a) = f(\overline{r}a))$

Here the "mapsto" symbol names a function by a formula for a variable. In a computer proof assistant like lean that can be done with λ(a:M)↦φ(a), though it's important to understand that this is a shorthand.

The key equation is this one:

$$\overline{r} \cdot_{R/\mathfrak{a}} f = r \cdot_{R} f$$

Which is actually the linearity of the map you gave (it's the linearity of the identity map on the underlying sets).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In order to evaluate your answer, could you, please, explain what the notation $f\otimes r $ means and what $a$ is. I am not sure if I understand what $a\mapsto rf(x)$ means. Thanks.

Comment: I made some edits. "a" was supposed to be the same as "x" so I fixed that.

Comment: OK, now, I see what you meant. I agree. However, this isomorphism seems to be not only isomorphism of $R/\mathfrak{a}$-modules, but also an isomorphism of $R$-modules, right?

Comment: Yes it is also a homomorphism of R-modules. If φ : A → B is a ring homomorphism and M is a B-module then M is an A-module using the formula (a,m)↦φ(a)m.

Comment: Indeed. I agree. If $M$ is separately an $R$ and an $R/\mathfrak{a}$-module,  and $\mathfrak{a}$ is in the annihilator of $N$ but it is not in the annihilator of $M$, is there still an isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}_{R}(M, N)\cong\mathrm{Hom}_{R/\mathfrak{a}}(M, N)$. The module structure on the $\mathrm{Hom}$-space is determined only by the module $N$. It is likely that we do not care about $M$ at all. I mean the concrete case of $R=\mathbb C[[t]]$ and $\mathfrak{a}=(t)$. Then the claim seems correct.